# Webpack exports only last file in bundle as a module

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm using webpack `4.30.0` and trying to build bundle several files each of them is exporting respective module with a name that reflects the name of the file.

For example: `phonecall.js` will export object `phonecall` and so on. Standard `ES6` modules are used.

All these files combined into `Form.js` which is exposed as a global object (library) with the name `Form`.

I expected that all modules used in bundle will be also exposed as properties of `Form`, but for any reason it's only the last one that is visible. In given example that would be `incident`. So after build I will be only one object globally available — `Form.incident`.

I believe it's by design, but I'm searching for a way how to change it for my particular case.

Is there any way how to make all child modules become available in exported library?

Here is my `webpack.config.js`:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    form: [
      './src/phonecall.js',
      './src/contact.js',
      './src/email.js',
      './src/incident.js',
    ],
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: '[name].js',
    library: 'Form',
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.LimitChunkCountPlugin({
      maxChunks: 1,
    }),
  ],
};
```

There is a workaround for this issue — is to create one central file that will be referencing all modules and re-exporting them, but this is an additional step and quite error prone procedure to follow.

Is there any out of the box solution to this question, how to expose all modules that belongs to bundle?

Comment: I would make a `form.js` file, that has all your exports on.. `module.exports = {phoneCall: require(".phonecall"), contact: require("./contact").....`  And then just make that the entry point.

Comment: Yes, I described that as workaround... But I'm trying to avoid it, since it's basically moving build configuration from `webpack` to another file...

Comment: It's not really webpacks job to bundle up static globals like this, and even it there was, I would strongly suggest you avoid it.  The more you make your code webpack specific, the more it becomes less portable.  What if later you wanted to use `system.js` / `rollup` / `pure ES6 modules` / `common.js / node modules` your library is then broken.   I'm also not sure how this would be any less error prone than creating this linkage inside a webpack config, and a Javascript file.